# Why does padding-left:50% stop working eventually?

Tags: html, css

I want to center a div, so I write `<div style="padding-left: 50%;">
    test
    </div>`. The text is centered just fine until I resize the browser to a very small size. (~300 px width). Then it starts to display a horizontal scrollbar.

Why do browsers (Chrome12, Opera11.50, Firefox5) implement that behaviour? In my mind that is simply not correct. There is no content that would need a scrollbar. How do I disable it or what else should I do to center my content?

Comment: "There is no content that would need a scrollbar" You mean the word 'test' is not content?

Comment: centred divs are usually taken care of with the margin property not the padding property. Different browsers handle padding differently so it's safer to use margin.

Comment: @BoltClock: The length of the text "test" is not long enough to merit a scrollbar at 300px browser. Why would a scrollbar start appearing then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to center text use `text-align:center`. If you want to center an element use `margin:0 auto`. Please provide more details about exactly what you wish to accomplish.

You can prevent the appearance of the scrollbar by modifying the [`overflow` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/overflow).

Comment: So my question was why my approach doesn't work. I mean, it should be pretty straightforward: I say: 50% padding to the left please. And it doesn't work?

Comment: @Blub, I cannot reproduce the behaviour you cite. See: http://jsfiddle.net/radu/K36Kq/show/. I've tested Chrome 12, FF3.6.7, Opera 11.10 and IE9 and I can't get a scrollbar to show up at a window width of 300px.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed width containers can be centered using margins.  Setting the left and right margin to auto will center your div.

```
<div style="width:900px;margin:0 auto;">
    test
</div>
```